# How to set up a multilingual website

Tags: php, internationalization, multilingual

I am trying to create an easy way to set up a multilingual website, with two languages - one which is the default and one which the user can switch to.

I would like to do this by loading both languages on each page, but only show the one selected.

When the user navigates the site I want the site to remember which language has been chosen, and display the text in that language.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The `display:none` approach seems to be inefficient (at least). What platform is the system supposed to run on? Java, PHP?

Comment: @ialencar On php. The site is created in wordpress

Comment: Exactly what is hard to understand with the question? O.o  And is it clearer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you are using Wordpress, the recommended approach is described here: [Translating Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress).

Answer (score 1):

To answer this in php and with the method mentioned:

```
<?php 
    $Languages = Array("English","Svenska","Deutsch");
    if(isset($_POST["lang"]))
    {
        foreach($Languages as $Possible)
        {
            if($_POST["lang"] == $Possible)
            {
                setcookie( "Lang", $_POST["lang"], strtotime( '+30 days' )); 
                $_COOKIE["Lang"] = $_POST["lang"];
            }
        }
    }
    $Lang = isset($_COOKIE["Lang"]) ? $_COOKIE["Lang"] : "English";
    $Tindex = 0;
    foreach($Languages as $Possible)
    {
        if($Possible == $Lang)
            $Index = $Tindex;
        $Tindex++;
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        <?php
            foreach($Languages as $Possible)
            {
                if($Lang != $Possible)
                {
                    echo ".language$Possible {";
                    echo "    display: none;";
                    echo "}";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <select name="lang">
            <?php
            foreach($Languages as $Possible)
            {
                echo "<option value='$Possible' " . ($Lang == $Possible ? "selected='true'" : "") . " >";
                echo "    $Possible";
                echo "</option>";
            } ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="pick language">
        </form>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1> Test case1: </h1>
        <div class="languageEnglish">
            Hello!
        </div>
        <div class="languageSvenska">
            Hallå!
        </div>
        <div class="languageDeutsch">
            Hallo!
        </div>
        <h1> Test case2: </h1>
        <div>
            <?php
                switch ($Lang) {
                    case "English":
                        echo "This is a test text!";
                        break;
                    case "Svenska":
                        echo "Denna text är en test text!";
                        break;
                    case "Deutsch":
                        echo "Dieses text ist einen test text!";
                        break;
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <h1> Test case3: </h1>
        <div>
        <?php
            $Str = Array("There are lots of ways to print the text!","Det finns massa sätt att skriva texten!","Es gibt viel methoden, die text zu schreiben!");
            echo $Str[$Index];
        ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you - this seems to be exactly what I am looking for! How would you switch between the two languages then?

Comment: @Kasper Bjerre Added the code =)

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much.
Would it be possible to have the languages as links in the top, instead of the dropdown?

Comment: Just tested it, and there is a problem - when I select a language the cookie only remembers my choice for the page I selected it on - if I navigate to another page, the default language is english, even if I have changed the language to Swedish on the previous page. Is it possible to fix this somehow? :)

Comment: @Kasper Bjerre it works for me =/  Does the cookie follow to the next page? Any errors? Make sure there is nothing before the first php code, not even a space.

Comment: @Kasper Bjerre Change the echoing of the options to '<input type="submit" value="$Possible" name="lang">'

Comment: If I select a language on one page, it is not changed for the other pages. But the cookie does remember my settings for the page I set the language on.
I am getting the header for my pages from the same includefile, could this have something to do with it?

Comment: @Kasper Bjerre may i see your code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22392/discussion-between-kasper-bjerre-and-zombiespy)